# Updating mongodb collection in C# Driver much slower than in shell

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongoDb collection with about 20k documents. Using the c# driver updating one document takes roughly 250ms. But looking at the mongodb log I get a "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0, so the update happens instantaneously if I understand it correctly

Is there a way to reduce the execution time or is this difference in execution time just inherent to the c# driver?

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
IMongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("Cities");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("City");

var timespan = DateTime.Now;
//update field result in document with given ObjectId
collection.UpdateOne(
        new BsonDocument{
             {"_id",new ObjectId("56d61033a378eccde8a8354f")}}
        ,Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("result","test"));

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(timespan));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do `new MongoClient()` it takes a bit of time to establish the connection to the database. and your first operations will take a few hundred milliseconds to complete. all operations after that should complete very fast (due to the driver's connection pooling). on my development machine, i'm seeing <5ms for inserts.

so make sure you're only creating the `client` once and re-using on all subsequent operations as mentioned in the [driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/connecting/#re-use).

Comment: If I understand the code snippet in the question correctly, the client creation is not measured.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic ah yes i did miss that. however, the very first operation is what establishes the connection to the db as far as i can remember. (not sure though). so it might pay to measure the time spent over a few iterations to see if subsequent updates do become quicker.

Comment: @RyanGunner you are completely right, the first update also establishes the connection that is why it takes a bit longer, following updates all run much faster at the expected speed, thank you, I completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you executing the same command. Async approach is considered to be modern these days. So, try

```
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
        new BsonDocument{
             {"_id",new ObjectId("56d61033a378eccde8a8354f")}}
        ,Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("result","test"));
```

Comment: the issue was with the first call having to establish the connection, but you are right that should ideally be an async method